# jQuery code only fires once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery code that fades out a div on click. I have an email tyoe list that each have a delete button, I want to fade out the div on click but it is only fading out the fist div. Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( "#message-close" ).click(function() {
     $( "#messages-wrapper" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
     });
   });
});
```

Say for example I have Ten divs, each wrapped in #messages-wrapper and using the #message-close button. But only the top div fades.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Provide jsfiddle.

Comment: Are your IDs unique? They have to be.

Comment: I can't provide a jfiddle because its a messaging email type system and would take me to long.  j08691 would creating usique IDs be hard? I'm not a coder, I just use id="message-close" for the divs now.

Comment: From the way you've described this, I definitely feel like j08691 is on to something - you cannot have multiple elements with the same ID. That being said, consider using *classes* for repeating elements, and using the `.`  selector, i.e. `$(".myClass")`

Comment: You are using the same ids on different items and this will make jquery stop working. Use a class instead

Comment: @Nick it isn't hard at all. Replace `id="message-close"` with `class="message-close"` and also replace `id="messages-wrapper"` with `class="messages-wrapper"`. Also make sure you update your jQuery to use `$(".message-close")` and `$(".messages-wrapper")`. It might not work though because you haven't shown us the HTML you have which could affect the result.

Comment: I changed the ids to classes but it deleted all the messages. I'm also confused because the divs show up on the fly so I'm not sure how I'd add an id to a div that's not there yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use class instead of id ( like this $( ".messages-wrapper" ) ) . Becouse unique id should be only once on the page. If you want to hide all div's, don't use ID. For example :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $( "#message-close" ).click(function() {
  $( ".messages-wrapper" ).fadeOut( "slow");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a different ID for each div.

`$("#message-close").click(function(){})` is called when you click the element with the `message-close` ID, and the fadeOut function is aiming the div with the `messages-wrapper` ID.

So each `click` function  has to aim the respective ID that you want to `fadeOut()`, and those IDs have to be different.

Comment: Here is my html. <button type="submit" class="message-close">